# Understanding Batch Job Behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

If we are creating 100 batch jobs at a time and each batch job will take around 2 mins for say. Then i need to understand whether batch jobs will run Sequentially or parallelly. If Sequentially , can i say we need to wait for the previous job to complete for the next batch job to start?

Comment: Without wanting to sound too presumptuous... Have you read the AWS docs on this subject? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_dependencies.html

Comment: In our requirement, there is no such dependency on previous jobs. So in that case what I need to understand is if I submitted 100 jobs at a same time, are they going to run sequentially or parallely?

Comment: Depends on so many things that haven't been specified in your question. i.e. How many compute environments have you associated to your queue? Are you submitting single jobs or array jobs? Given the information you have provided, all I can say is: it's likely your jobs will execute in parallel.

Comment: We are using 1 compute environment and the type of job is Single Job.